# animation by setInterval

Tags: javascript

i want to make an animation using setInterval. The image has to change its position from left to right.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>animacja</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #obrazek
    {
        position: relative;
        left: 1px;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="animacja.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <img src="smile.jpg" id="obrazek" alt="Usmiech" width="100" height="100" />
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = inicjuj;


function inicjuj()
{
    setInterval(function(){animacja();},1000);
}

function animacja()
{
    var obj = document.getElementById("obrazek");
    var wartosc = parseInt(obj.style.left, 10);
    obj.style.left = (wartosc + 10) + "px";
}
```

Unfortunalety js doesn't work and i don't know why. I've checked and the animacja function runs however the image isn't changing its position.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it also doesn't work regardless of the position's value :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `obj.style` only contains information about styles that are specified in the `style` tag, *not* style specified in other style sheets, like your `<style>` tag. Thus, `obj.style.left` is the empty string, and `parseInt('')` yields `NaN`.

**Instead**, define your `left` style property in the `style` property of the `<img>` tag:

```
<img ... style="left:1px;" />
```

**Or**, if it's very important to keep the styles in separate (e.g. to adhere to some design standard), you can use the [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) function to figure out the object's actual `left` style value:

```
function animacja()
{
    var obj = document.getElementById("obrazek");
    var wartosc = parseInt(getComputedStyle(obj).left, 10);
    console.log(parseInt(getComputedStyle(obj).left, 10))
    obj.style.left = (wartosc + 10) + "px";
}​
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a minor bug in your code..

Initially as the `left property` of the element is **not defined** , it is empty . So `parseInt` returns **NaN..**

Just add a extra check condition.

```
window.onload = inicjuj;


function inicjuj()
{
    setInterval(animacja,1000);
}

function animacja()
{
    var obj = document.getElementById("obrazek");
    var left = obj.style.left;
    if(left === ''){
        left = 0;
    }
    var wartosc = parseInt(left, 10);
    obj.style.left = (wartosc + 10) + "px";
}​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/eCSb4/)**